# javaScript appendChild property

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript

```
var selectOption2 = document.createElement("option");
        // alert(selectOption2);
         selectOption2.value = results[i].Name;
         alert(selectOption2.value);
         selectOption2.innerText = results[i].Name;
         alert(selectOption2.innerText);
         //alert(selectOption2.value);

        selectListItems2.appendChild(selectOption2);
```

I have a sharepoint list and Name is a column in that list.
I am trying to get that name column value using javascript but it is showing undefined instead of the actual value of name column.

for title field and other field, the same code is working but it is not working for name field.

I have used the above code, is there anything wrong with the code.

Comment: are you using REST api for getting the data ?

Comment: what does the results indicate ? is it a variable or rest result ?

Comment: Check console.log(results) gives you

Comment: Name is an existing SharePoint columnname, so I suspect your Name column has a different InternalName